# JQuery sticky panel working in all browsers except Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I've got this code below which is used to make a div panel fixed when you scroll to a certain point on the screen. This works fine in most browsers it just doesn't work in Google Chrome. Any ideas why?

The problem is that when the page gets half way down the page the sticky panel releases as if it's the bottom of the page. I have tried to comment the code to make it easier to understand.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Set up variables
        var panelTD = $('#stickyPanel');
        var panelDiv = $('#stickyPanelDiv');
        var screenHeight = $(window).height();
        var pageHeight = $(document).height();
        var topOfPanel = panelDiv.offset().top;
        var panelHeight = panelDiv.height();
        var floatingHeight = panelHeight;
        var panelScroll = panelDiv.scrollTop();

        var scrollEvent = function () {

            var topOfPage = $(document).scrollTop();

            // Reset screen height if needed
            if (screenHeight != $(window).height())
            {
                screenHeight = $(window).height();
            }

            // Change floating height depending on screen height
            if ((screenHeight - 52) < panelHeight)
            {
                floatingHeight = (screenHeight - 52);
            }
            else
            {
                floatingHeight = panelHeight;
            }

            // Bottom of page
            if ((pageHeight - (panelHeight + 144 - panelScroll)) < topOfPage)
            {
                panelTD.css('vertical-align', 'bottom');
                panelDiv.css({
                    'bottom': '52px',
                    'position': 'static',
                    'height': panelHeight,
                    'overflow-y': 'visible'
                });
                panelDiv.mouseover(function () { $(this).css('overflow-y', 'visible'); });
            }
            // Fixed in the middle
            else if (topOfPage > (topOfPanel - 52))
            {
                panelDiv.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'height': floatingHeight,
                    'overflow-y': 'hidden'
                });
                panelDiv.mouseover(function () { $(this).css('overflow-y', 'scroll'); });
                panelDiv.mouseout(function () { $(this).css('overflow-y', 'hidden'); });

                // Set fixed div scroll position
                if (panelScroll != 0)
                {
                    if ((topOfPage - (topOfPanel - 52)) < panelScroll)
                    {
                        panelDiv.scrollTop(topOfPage - (topOfPanel - 52));
                    }
                }

            }
            // Top of page
            else
            {
                panelTD.css('vertical-align', 'top');
                panelDiv.css({
                    'position': 'static',
                    'height': panelHeight,
                    'overflow-y': 'visible'
                });
                panelDiv.mouseover(function () { $(this).css('overflow-y', 'visible'); });
            }
        };

        // Fixed div scroll event
        panelDiv.scroll(function () {
            panelScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        });

        // Main window scroll event
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            scrollEvent();
        });
    });
```

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful. Also, look into the syntax for assigning multiple css properties in a single block, and assign your div to a variable. It makes your code much lighter.

Comment: Thanks I'll put together a fiddle now and look into assigning multiple CSS properties in a single block

Comment: I've managed to solve this by trying to create a fiddle! It was some styling I was applying to the floating div. Thanks for the advice @isherwood

Comment: Sure. Please provide and accept an answer below, or delete your question.